# Un-register service from hwservicemanager

Tags: services, fingerprint

I have disabled the fingerprint sensor on my phone by setting the device tree node status to disabled. When I boot up, the fingerprint menu options are gone, but dmesg shows that `hwservicemanager` is trying to start a fingerprint sensor over and over, but init can't find the service:

```
[  625.488742] init: Could not find 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' for ctl.interface_start
[  625.502583] init: Received control message 'interface_start' for 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' from pid: 669 (/system/bin/hwservicemanager)
[  625.502658] init: Could not find 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' for ctl.interface_start
[  625.523352] init: Received control message 'interface_start' for 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' from pid: 669 (/system/bin/hwservicemanager)
[  625.523427] init: Could not find 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' for ctl.interface_start
[  625.538080] init: Received control message 'interface_start' for 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' from pid: 669 (/system/bin/hwservicemanager)
[  625.538545] init: Could not find 'android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default' for ctl.interface_start
```

How do I tell `hwservicemanager` to stop trying to start this now non-existent service? I saw [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/dEc5fJALiqI) that there is an option to remove the hidl definitions from a manifest file, but I would like to enable or disable the fingerprint sensor at runtime. I can enable and disable the service with `start vendor.fps_hal` and `stop vendor.fps_hal`, but I can't stop `hwservicemanager` from trying to start it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [system/hwservicemanager/ServiceManager.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:system/hwservicemanager/ServiceManager.cpp;l=259) to see when and why `hwservicemanager` is setting `ctl.interface_start` to trigger `init` to start the HAL service.

Unless you are willing to update `system/hwservicemanager/ServiceManager.cpp`, I don't see a way to achieve what you are trying to do.